# WCF interacting (callback) with .Net 2.0 app

Tags: wcf

At first I had to make 2.0 work with WCF service. I accomplished that using BasicHttpBinding . Since BasicHttpBinding doesn't support Duplex callback, I can't make the server ping the client. Any ideas????
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want WCF to do this, it's not possible over the `BasicHttpBinding`.  You need `wsDualHttpBinding` or `NetTcpBinding` if you wish to establish a callback channel out-of-the-box with WCF.  You can also try to write a [CustomBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793.aspx), but utilizing .NET 2.0 for the client is going to limit what you can do.

Comment: To my understanding, only BasicHttpBinding is compatible with .Net 2.0. Can I use wsDualHttpBinding (seems promising) or NetTcpBinding compatible with .net 2.0. Also we can't use IIS.