# How to invoke WCF (written in .Net 4.5) service from client which is written in .Net 2.0

Tags: .net, wcf

There is an old application which is written in .Net 2.0 (runtime) but we want to consume a WCF service (hosted using SVC) which is written in .Net 4.5.

Can simply by adding it's reference in the client (.net 2.0) web reference, will work?

Comment: Have you tried it? WCF should be mostly platform agnostic... so I would think it would also be .net framework agnostic.

Comment: I tried, but its not working out. Does it not support Net TCP based binding? Is the issue because, i am not using basic http binding and net tcp?

Comment: Web References only support basicHttpBinding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF service (.NET 4.0) can have a .NET 2.0 client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479569/wcf-service-net-4-0-can-have-a-net-2-0-client)